# Android ListView not showing newly added items and erasing old items when switching content views

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a custom listview defined in my xml layout file. I can add items to this ListView inside `onCreate` method, through an array adapter.

However when I add items from another content view and then go back to the content view with the ListView all the items are gone and there's nothing listed. Even after calling `.notifyDataSetChanged();`

It seems like I can only add to the list when the content view containing the ListView is currently being displayed. Is this the default behavior?

**Failed attempted workaround**

I used another array to keep the newly added items and then try to add them when the ListView became visible again. I had to override `onContentChanged()` to do so but then no items were added still.

So the main question is

### How can I dynamically add items to the ListView even if it's out of sight and still preserve the old items?

PS: I have to say the Android API is ***one of the worst*** I've ever come across.

Comment: What do you mean by "another content view"?

Comment: @TomaszGawel I have a couple of layouts that I switch to dynamically using `setContentView()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change content view, then all the previous views are going to be destroyed. Are you using an adapter? If so, then it would be very easy to add all the items to the list again.

There shouldn't be any reason to setContentView any time other than in onCreate.

If you were looking to have multiple screens, instead of changing content view, then start a new activity.

Comment: This makes sense. I'll try this for now and will get back to you quickly.

Comment: Ok. So we've established that the best way is to have multiple Activities and it works fine now.

Answer (score -1):

dynamically add items:

```
//add at the top of the list
mListView.addHeaderView(itemView);
// add at the bottom of the list
mListView.addFooterView(itemView);
```

Comment: I can add anything but when coming back to the content view the items get erased.

Comment: You can technically add more than one header or footer, so this would work - but this is a hack, the original poster needs to be able to add elements to the backing array of his ListView, not add a Header or Footer (which are ancillary to the original backing data)